# Ace Editor Cursor Current Position in Numeric Index

Tags: count, ace-editor, caret, string-length, cursor-position

Is there exist any function or logic that can count total character before current position of cursor (caret) in ace editor?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

there are positionToIndex and indexToPosition methods on session.doc

```
editor.session.doc.positionToIndex(editor.selection.getCursor())
```

note that this iterates over all lines before cursor, so can be slow for some usecases.

Comment: how to achieve this goal via Ace.Range to boost function speed